# How to prove that polyhedron is a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization

Given the definition of polyhedron, $\{x \in R^n : Ax \leq b\} $

Comment: What definitions and theorems do you have to work with?  For example, can you make use of the theorem that the intersection of closed sets is itself closed?  Do you have a theorem that a half space is closed?

Answer (score 1):

For $(a_i)_{i=1}^n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$

Is $\{(x_i)_{i=1}^n \in \mathbb{R}^n|\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i \leq b \}$ a closed set ?

Remark : I have noted that some of the litterature on polyhedrons, and more generally operations research, has very complicated proofs for results that are very simple given a little topology. They often have good reasons to do it, like introducing some algorithm, but it has a "proof complexity" cost. Best be aware of this.